# Google Script - Calendar events not owned by me

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a script to delete event invites from my personal google calendar. I get invited to multiple events everyday such as "Click here to win an iPhone" etc.

I have written a google script to run each hour and delete any events where I am not the owner. However this is getting all events and then iterating through them to see if I am the owner in a for loop. This seems quite inefficient and takes a long time to run.

Is there a better way to achieve this.

Current code below:

```
function deleteScamCalendarInvites() {

  var date = new Date();
  var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
  var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear() + 5, date.getMonth(), 1);

  var myCalendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var myEvents = myCalendar.getEvents(firstDay, lastDay);

  for(var i in myEvents){
    if(myEvents[i].isOwnedByMe() == false){
       var eventId = myEvents[i];
       eventId.deleteEvent();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you can try and play around with the q search paramater for events.list it says its full text search on all fields i tried creator.self=false not sure if it works or not.   Its the only thing i can think of

Comment: Does Google Apps support filter functions by chance?